# Textfields/TextViews won't add to scrollview iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to add a `textView` and `textField` as `subViews` to my `scrollView`. The `scrollView` shows up nice and green, but the `textView` and `textField` objects are not showing up inside the scrollView.

Here is the method

```
- (void) readerView: (ZBarReaderView*) view
     didReadSymbols: (ZBarSymbolSet*) syms
          fromImage: (UIImage*) img
{
    // do something useful with results
    for(ZBarSymbol *sym in syms) {
    self.symbolData = (NSString*)sym.data;
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 20, 20)];
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 240,20,20)];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 80)];
    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    textView.text = self.symbolData;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView addSubview:textField];
    [scrollView addSubview:textView];

    break;
    }
}
```

This method gets called once I move my devices camera over a bar code that can be scanned.

I have also seen many similar questions on this site, and my code looks like the answers to the questions I have seen, but I can't figure out why its not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a problem that your scrollview is only 80 pixels tall but the views you are adding to it have a y coordinate of 200 and 240?  Scrollviews by default clip to bounds, so you will never see your subviews if they are off the scrollview's screen.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I knew it was something silly like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer.

Your scrollview is only 80 units tall.  The subviews you are adding have a y coordinate of 200 and 240, so they are off the scrollview's visible height.  Scrollviews by default are set to clip to their bounds, so anything out of their bounds will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace your these three lines

```
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView addSubview:textField];
[scrollView addSubview:textView];
```

With

```
[scrollView addSubview:textField];
[scrollView addSubview:textView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

> First add the subViews to the scrollview then add the scrollView to
>   the view. Or Globally define your scrollView.